# Big Picture object and Memory Deallocation

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap

I want to free memory as `Bitmap.recycle();` does in bitmaps , ASAP.

What is best preferred techniques  to do that , knowing i am handling `OutOfMemoryError` in catch.

There is not such `recycle()` function in case of `Picture` class.

How should i handle this? Will `System.gc()` be useful.

Comment: Reduce size of your image.. you won't control environment of your user's device..

Comment: can Picture object be directly resized ?

Comment: Think it like this.. you are downloading some image in bitmap form, it will be stored in memory. then you are going to resize it.. now the problem is, in some cases, while downloading image you will get `OutOfMemoryError`. So, I would suggest you to get a lower sized images to download. This will solve the problem for sure..